# WhatsApp Phone number Regex

Tags: android, mobile, numbers, whatsapp

I'm trying to make this Regex allow this symbol **-**

For Example this Phone Number is not matching right now +212 659-639217

So I need some one to help me change the Regex to allow it please
**Here is the Regex:**

`^\+(?:[0-9]\x20?){6,14}[0-9]$`

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

`([+]*\d{3,})*\s?\d{3}[-]?\d{6}`

- Optional plus sign
- Optional space (between country code and the rest)
- Optional dash

## Update

`\+\d{3}[ ]?(\d+(-| )?)+`

1. Expect plus sign.
2. Expect 3 digit number (country code).
3. Optional whitespace.
4. Any number of digits followed by an **optional** dash OR a whitespace
5. Repeat the previous step for 1 or more times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this won't help. Because I am trying to only accept the format that is used by WhatsApp. Some numbers might have multiple spaces or multiple Dashes. I am not sure why but when i tried your answer it only accepted 1 space and 1 dash. Also the Plus sign has to be mandatory Here some more examples of the format on WA.+962 7 4567 123
+967 773-123-123
+212 627-024321
+212 689-881234
+966 54 666 4373
My apologies if I didn't make it clear from the start, but the numbers above cover 99% of the cases. I would appreciate any help, thanks and regards dear

Comment: @AonKhries I have updated my answer. if that expression caused some false positives, please post them here.